# Python: adding a new item to a dict of lists using an old item

Tags: python

Since appending to a list updates the list wherever it might be, the below form of adding a new item to a dictionary of lists using a old item does not work:

```
>>> d = {1: [1]}
>>> d[2] = d[1].append(3)
>>> d
{1: [1, 3], 2: None}
```

I wrote some cumbersome code to solve this problem. What about this problem?

```
>>> d = {1: [1], 2:[1, 3]}
>>> # add a new item for each item where k*=3 and 5 is appended to d[k]
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `d[2] = d[1] + [3]`?  Not sure if I'm understanding your question.

Comment: @BrenBarn I have to chuckle about forgetting the obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you got `None` for 2 in your dict is that `append` is an in-place operation that returns `None`.

If you want to build up a new list, you might try:

```
>>> d = {1: [1]}
>>> d[2] = d[1] + [3]
>>> d
{1: [1], 2: [1, 3]}
```

But I can't think of a good reason to do this. If all you're doing semantically is building a list with indexes, you can do this, just keep in mind that Python starts counting indexes and slices at 0:

```
>>> l = [1]
>>> l.append(3)
>>> l
[1, 3]
>>> l[0]
1
>>> l[1]
3
```